# C# LINQ query from .xlsx file to JSON

Tags: c#, json, excel, linq, visual-studio

I'm pretty new to C# and need a little help trying to get the correct range of data from a spreadsheet.

Is there a way in the LINQ query portion of the below code to specify which exact column/s and row/s to extract from the data-set(not sure if correct terminology)? Is this the correct approach?

Currently it seems I can only get specified column/s.

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var pathToExcel = @"C:\Users\ab\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\data\HouseholdIncomeData2014.xlsx";
            var sheetName = "hinc01";
            var destinationPath = @"C:\Users\ab\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Project1\Project1\data\HouseholdIncomeData.json";

            //data is saved in a .xlsx file
            var connectionString=String.Format(@"
                Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                Data Source={0};
                Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES""
            ",pathToExcel);

            //Creating and opening a data connection to the Excel sheet 
            using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = String.Format(
                    @"SELECT * FROM [hinc01$B95:AQ107]", //@"SELECT * FROM [{0}$]"
                    sheetName
                );

                using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    //LINQ query will create anonymous objects for each row
                    var query =
                        from DbDataRecord row in rdr
                        select new
                        {
                            //blah1 = row[0],
                            //blah2 = row[1],
                            //blah3 = row[2]

                            name = row[0]
                        };

                    //Generates JSON using LINQ query
                    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query);

                    //Write the file to the destination path    
                    File.WriteAllText(destinationPath, json);

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use OLEDB to read the Excel file. There is an excellent (no pun intended) NuGet package that makes working with Excel files very convenient: [ExcelDataReader](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader/).